# ng commands take a lot of time to start

Tags: angular, wsl-2

I have a problem with Angular: every time I type a command (`ng --version`, `ng serve`, etc..) it takes a lot of time for the command to start.

For example `ng serve` takes 1 minute and 5 seconds to start, and only 10 seconds to compile, `ng --version` takes about 15 seconds.
If I use the command `time ng server` (which doesn't exist), the output is the following:

```
The specified command ("server") is invalid. For a list of available options,
run "ng help".

Did you mean "serve"?

real    0m12.788s
user    0m2.277s
sys     0m1.574s
```

[image: these are my computers' stats]

I am working on WSL2, Ubuntu 20.04 (***installed on a secondary disk***, an HDD, not an SSD). I previously had npm installed on windows, but I removed it after installing npm on the subsystem.

I found this ISSUE on github, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3484 but it isn't helping much.

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 10.0.5
Node: 10.19.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 10.0.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1000.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.5
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.5
@angular/cli                      10.0.5
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.5
@schematics/angular               10.0.5
@schematics/update                0.1000.5
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.9.7
webpack                           4.43.0
```

`npm --version`: 6.14.4

`nodejs --version`: v10.19.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found that running `time ng --version` in the home directory, outputs:

```
real    0m0.620s
user    0m0.662s
sys     0m0.042s
```

and `time ng serve` outputs

```
real    0m10.523s
user    0m13.233s
sys     0m0.762s
```

Ok, so this is my final solution: I move the projects created with the linux subsystem in the home directory (Which is in the secondary disk at the end of the day). This is an WSL2 issue, it makes accesses to mnt really slow.